# DataGridView binding without screen freeze

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, datagridview

I'm developing an windows application, now i need to fill `datagridview` with large amount of data. How can i achieve this without screen freezing.

## dgvRpt.DataSource = dataTable;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this by using BackgroundWorker

```
BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker(); 
bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork); 
bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); 

private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
{ 
    dgvRpt.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate 
    { 
            dgvRpt.DataSource = yourDataTable; 
    })); 
}
```